# Version controlled tree structure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, version-control, tree

Consider a hierarchical file system where each *folder* maintains a version history (i.e. name and additional properties may change). I need to implement this in `MySQL 5.1` but a future version may be ported to `SQL Server 2012`.

I understand there are several options for tree-structures in databases:

- [Adjacency List](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)
- [Nested Set](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) (may cause extremely slow insertions)
- [Nested intervals](http://arxiv.org/html/cs.DB/0401014) (complex stuff, requires support for recursion...)

These techniques have been discussed on StackOverflow before. However, my problem adds another dimension to the problem as I need to maintain a history for each node. The data that needs to be maintained can be seen as a list of properties. E.g. Name, date, type...

**Some premises**

- The database is expected to handle 5-10 simultaneous clients.
- The tree is expected to grow up to a 1000-5000 parent nodes (with an arbitrary number of leafs).
- Nodes may be inserted at any time.
- Nodes/leafs may *never* be updated or deleted. Insted, a version history is maintained.
- Reorganization of nodes is not permitted. (Though, if possible, this would be nice to have!)
- Multiple clients may simultaneously add/modify tree nodes. Hence, the clients need to continuously re-read the tree structure (no need for real-time updates).
- Order of importance: Traceability (crucial), performance, scalability.

**Q: What is the preferred technique of choice for the tree structure and its version controlled node data?** SQL samples are appreciated, but not mandatory.

Comment: There is also **Closure** model. See: [Models for Hierarchical Data](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data)

Comment: @ypercube, Closure is indeed the optimal solution. Please answer the question :)

Comment: attribute version control is orthogonal to hierarchical data. Use a table to store the current attribute values, and a second table to store past values with versioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Versioning is extremely tricky because you are dealing with time varying data and neither of the databases you have suggested (or any others that I am aware of) have native support for doing this simply.

Please have a read of [Developing Time-Oriented Database Applications in SQL](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/people/rts/tdbbook.pdf); the book may be almost 15 years old but the issues are largely unchanged.

The fact that you mention **"Traceability (crucial)"** suggests that you are going to want to get this right.

When considering a simple report to show just the heirachy, the issues you need to consider are do you need to know:

- what the tree looks like today, using today's data (yes, obviously)
- what the tree looks like now, using last week's data
- what the tree looks like a week ago, using the today's data
- what the tree looks like a week ago, using last week's data
- what the tree looks like a week ago, using the week before last's data

The issues you face are because you are dealing with time varying data, that is updated at a different time from the real-world process it is modeling, that in itself may be dealing with temporal data. Anyway, read the book.

**If** this is a non-issue (i.e. the tree is static), then @didierc is correct in his comment, the nodes of the tree can refer to an external versioning table. However, if you also need to store versioning information about the heirachy itself this approach won't work if implemented naively (using whatever model).

To give a concrete example, consider a simple tree valid at 1/1/13 - A->B->C. If this changes on 1/2/13 to A->D->B->C. If you run a query on 1/3/13, referring back to 1/2/13, which tree do you want to retrieve?

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We ended up using Closure tables with timestamps. It's clean and robust and seems to fit our needs.